# rufus-scheduler runs scheduler multiple times due to unicorn workers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unicorn, rufus-scheduler

I had setup scheduler in my rails3 projects's /configs/initializers/schedule.rb and it working fine, But it works 2 times and I think it is due to unicorn workers execute schedule at the same time, so it create in my database two records each time. 
I checked my logic and its ok and enter single record in my local machine.

I checked following but not getting idea how to stop multiple unicorn workers to execute scheduler?

https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/#advanced-lock-schemes

Any one got this issue? Please help if any idea.

Thanks,

P Shah

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new(:lockfile => ".rufus-scheduler.lock")

unless scheduler.down?

  scheduler.every("60") do
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: if there are more than one scheduler try changing the lock name as
      
.rufus-scheduler2.lock

Answer (score 0):

Please try the solution described in https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/#lockfile--mylockfiletxt

Comment: OK, then I guess I can't help you