# job gets executed twice working with resque and rufus scheduler on development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque, rufus-scheduler, resque-scheduler

I am working with resque and rufus scheduler.

I have created two different queues for the two different resque jobs and able to execute both the queues.

But I am facing one issue as **both the queues are executing twice every time.**

Here is the **Scheduler.rb** file :

*Directory : config/initializers/scheduler.rb*

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rufus/scheduler'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

scheduler.cron '46 19 * * *' do
  Resque::Job.create(:monitoring_queue, Monitoring)
end

scheduler.every '60m' do
  Resque::Job.create(:execute_monitoring_queue, ExecuteMonitor)
end
```

Here is the resque job file-1 **monitoring.rb**

```
class Monitoring
  @queue = :monitoring_queue
  def self.perform()
    begin
      Monitor.check_and_confirm
      NotificationMailer.notification_email.deliver
    rescue Exception => e
      puts e.message
      e.backtrace.join("\n")
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the resque job file-2 **execute_monitor.rb**

```
class ExecuteMonitor
  @queue = :execute_monitoring_queue
  def self.perform()
    begin
      Monitor.confirm_and_check
      NotificationMailer.notification_email.deliver
    rescue Exception => e
      puts e.message
      e.backtrace.join("\n")
    end
  end
end
```

can any please tell me why those queues are executing twice every time or is there something that I am missing.

Just let me know anything needed.

Comment: Do you have two processes running this code? That would cause it to be queued twice.

Comment: I second Chris. Indicating what server you use (Unicorn, Thin, Webrick, Puma, etc) and in what mode would help too.

Comment: I am using Apache server

Answer (score 0):

Not directly an answer, but could help:

- [Issue with rufus-scheduler when we have multiple EC2 instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26943246/issue-with-rufus-scheduler-when-we-have-multiple-ec2-instances)
- [Rufus scheduler running multiple times with unicorn, fixed with :lockfile, but how to eliminate the error msg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23556556/rufus-scheduler-run-multiple-times-with-unicorn-fixed-with-filelock-but-how-t)
- [rufus-scheduler runs scheduler multiple times due to unicorn workers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958902/rufus-scheduler-runs-scheduler-multiple-times-due-to-unicorn-workers)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rufus-scheduler ...

In the rufus-scheduler documentation:

- https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler#lockfile--mylockfiletxt
- https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler#scheduler_lock
- https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler#advanced-lock-schemes